# How can I test the quality of a video call over an extended period of time?

Tags: monitoring, video-conferencing, connection-speed

I'm looking for a way to test the quality of a video call over a long duration -- e.g. 1 hour. I'm aware of internet speed tests and such, but these will test internet speed only over a short period of time -- e.g. 20 seconds -- and I have the sense that video calls "quality" of the call is often determined by the period of time during the call when the connection was worst. I am therefore seeking software that would maintain some kind of video call in an automated way over a long period of time -- e.g. 1 hour -- and report metrics on the call's overall quality, such as the worst latency experienced during the call. Do you know of any such software?